# WSL Ubuntu 20.04, The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 2 distro

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having an issue with running Docker commands in Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL.

I followed the official documentation to setup Docker and run it with Ubuntu on WSL distribution.

Now, I want to do the same in another distribution, Ubuntu 20.04.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Using PowerShell with admin privileges, Ubuntu 20.04 is shown and set as the default, according to the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/):

   ```
   wsl.exe -l -v
   wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2
   wsl.exe --set-default-version 2
   ```
2. With Docker desktop application, *Resources* --> *WSL Integration*, `Ubuntu-20.04` is added and Docker restarted and shown as active.
3. In the regular Ubuntu WSL distribution, I get the following:

   ```
   george@DESKTOP-P9I14LM:~$ ls -l /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin
   total 158574
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 60513128 May 12  2022 com.docker.cli
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 60178432 May 31  2022 docker
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6348800 May 31  2022 docker-compose
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12737304 May 31  2022 docker-compose-v1
   -rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  9395712 May 31  2022 docker-credential-desktop.exe
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13205504 May 31  2022 hub-tool
   ```

   While on Ubuntu-20.04 I get `No such file or directory`.
4. On Ubuntu 20.04:

   ```
   george@DESKTOP-P9I14LM:~$ ls -la  /usr/bin/docker
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Dec  4 12:52 /usr/bin/docker -> 
   /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/docker

   george@DESKTOP-P9I14LM:~$ ls /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/
   ls: cannot access '/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/bin/': No such file or directory
   ```

Am not familiar with this kind of issues, so please let me know in comments if there is any missing info I should add.

Comment: In the 20.04 distribution, what does `ls -l /mnt/wsl` show?

Comment: Personally, I've found simply installing Docker natively in WSL is a much better experience than the abortion that is Docker Desktop.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds It returns total 0, its an empty directory

Comment: @George Hmm.  So it sounds like `/mnt/wsl` tmpfs isn't getting mounted in the 20.04 instance.  What's `uname -a` show, and is there a `/etc/wsl.conf`?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thank you for your time, the `uname -a` is returning the following `Linux DESKTOP-P9I14LM 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` , And no, There are no /etc/wsl.conf